# Reading binary stream from USB serial device

Tags: linux, serial-port, asterisk

I'm working on a patch for [chan_dongle](http://code.google.com/p/asterisk-chan-dongle/) for Huawei e177 modems which has one way audio problem.

For debugging purpose I decided to write an external test case to read and write audio from and to the modem but I was unable the receive the audio stream in any of the serial files after the modem was mounted. I use minicom to issue the commands, I pick up an incoming call using the relevant AT command but no bytes stream arrives to any file. The only output I receive is from the AT command in `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

I am trying to capture audio with:

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB1
```

I also tried modifying the terminal settings and then read

```
 stty -F /dev/ttyUSB1 115200 cs8 -cstopb -parenb -cooked min 1 time 0
```

Is there any extra step I'm missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an incoming call is answered with ATA, the modem needs to know where the audio stream should be sent, **AT^DDSETEX=** does this for us.

I was missing that part. [Here](http://caruizdiaz.com/?p=294) I explain the background and the solution for my question.

Thanks for the clues.

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk do lock of tty,so you cna't connect same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture an audio stream from Asterisk, then you're going to need to use EAGI or JACK.  There is no other way, as asterisk needs to have complete control over the "master" devices.  Otherwise, it would crash and burn (well, worse than it does sometimes).

Comment: I managed to get it to work. I was missing the AT^DDSETEX=<diag-port> after the ATA.